Is it possible to only mention arguments which change between overloads in Python?
I have a function whose return type varies based on the value of one of it's arguments:
class ReturnType(Enum):
    NONE = 1
    SCALAR = 2
    VECTOR = 3


@overload
def perform_query(
    sql: str, return_type: Literal[ReturnType.NONE], log_query: bool = ...
) -> None: ...

@overload
def perform_query(
    sql: str, return_type: Literal[ReturnType.SCALAR], log_query: bool = ...
) -> int | float | bool | str: ...

@overload
def perform_query(
    sql: str, return_type: Literal[ReturnType.VECTOR], log_query: bool = ...
) -> list[int | float | bool | str]: ...

def perform_query(
    sql: str, return_type: ReturnType, log_query: bool = False
):
    pass

This is fine, but there's a lot of boilerplate: only one parameter changes between overloads, but every other parameter must be written out identically each time.
This creates redundancy and isn't very DRY. (Imagine if I wanted to rename an input parameter, or if my function had many input arguments.)
Is there a way to avoid restating the arguments which don't change?

No, that's the best available solution. If there were many arguments after return_type, you could try something with unpacked TypedDict, but with three args it won't be ergonomic. Your overload code looks pretty idiomatic and sane, I don't think repeating parameters in overload signatures violates DRY.

If you have many such functions (with same args), consider writing a Protocol once and casting to it via decorator.
